# How to ignore start on input in hive insert query

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hive, impala

I have data format in tab separated
State:ca city:california population:1M

I want to create DB, when I do insert I should ignore "state:" , "city:" and "poulation" and I want to insert state into state database with population and city into city table with population.

There will be 2 tables then one with state and population the other with city and population

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CSP.original 
(
    st STRING COMMENT 'State', 
    ct STRING COMMENT 'City', 
    po STRING COMMENT 'Population'
) 
COMMENT 'Original Table' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

this didn't work. It added comment but it didn't ignore.
And I also I want to create 2 tables for state and city. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Very confusing your question. Please me more clear

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create external table first.

Step1:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE all_info (state STRING, population INT) PARTITIONED BY (date STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t;
```

Step2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state (state string, population INT) PARTITIONED BY (date string);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city (city string, population INT) PARTITIONED BY (date string);
```

Step3:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE state
PARTITION (date = ‘201707076’)
SELECT *
FROM all_info
WHERE date = ‘20170706’ AND
              instr(state, ‘state:’) = 1;  
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE city
PARTITION (date = ‘201707076’)
SELECT *
FROM all_info
WHERE date = ‘20170706’ AND
              instr(state, ‘city:’) = 1;
```